# Sequence of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Here is a question that I came uo with and that's been on my mind for days now.

Let
$$E_n  \;:\;\;\;  f^{(n+1)}-f^{(n)}=0$$
and $S_n$ denote the solutions of $E_n$. Prove that the following holds
$$S_n\subsetneq S_{n+1}.$$
If possible, give a description of $S_n$.

*Attempt at a proof* :
If $f$ satisfies $E_n$ then differentiating both sides shows that $f$ satisfies $E_{n+1}$. Polynomials of order $n$ satisfy $E_{n+1}$ but not $E_{n}$

For the description of $S_n$, I know that it must include polynomials of order less than $n$, and then functions $Ae^x$. Is there anything else?

Comment: Your conclusion about what $S_n$ contains is right. Btw, you can just solve this equation :) it's a linear homogeneous equation.

Comment: You are right. Is there such a thing as $S_\infnty$?

Comment: I'm not good at limit objects if they don't come from analysis (and especially not good if they come from topology or category theory) :) I even can't remember what is the right name for object $\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} S_n$ which is to me natural candidate to be called $S_{\infty}$.